# Может ли компилятор изменять порядок полей класса?

Tags: c++, оптимизация

```
struct POD
{
int a;
float b;
char c;
double d;
};

class NoPOD
{
public:
int a;
private:
char b;
static float c;
};

float NoPOD::c=12;
```

Может ли компилятор изменять порядок полей класса?

Если структура является POD или не является POD.

Когда чаще всего это происходит?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Порядок определен только для полей с одной и той же видимостью. В приведенном примере поля структуры POD будут иметь строго заданный порядок, а в NoPOD поля `a` и `b` могут быть изменены местами.

> **12.2 Class members [class.mem]**
>   18 Non-static data members of a (non-union) class with the same access control (Clause 14) are allocated so that later members have higher addresses within a class object. The order of allocation of non-static data members with different access control is unspecified (Clause 14). Implementation alignment requirements might cause two adjacent members not to be allocated immediately after each other; so might requirements for space for managing virtual functions (13.3) and virtual base classes (13.1).

Answer (score 2):

Порядок объявления полей класса должен "соблюдаться" операторами сравнения указателей `<`, `>` и т.п., то есть соответствовать порядку объявления, при условии, что сравниваемые поля имеют одинаковый уровень доступа. Каким образом компилятор соблюдет это требование: обеспечением такого же физического порядка полей в памяти или через "компиляторную магию" - не оговаривается. Но на практике это означает, что ни один здравомыслящий компилятор не будет физически переупорядочивать поля в классе, если эти поля имеют одинаковый уровень доступа.

Что касается полей с разным уровнем доступа, то переупорядочивание для них вполне возможно (с сохранением относительного порядка в рамках каждого уровня доступа).